# Angular-js - dynamically create navi

Tags: angularjs, navigation

I'm new to Angularjs and have sat through many tutorials to improve my knowledge. All tutorials show me how to use $routeProvider to load templates into view. However they only show me examples that assume the routes are known and I would like to learn how to dynamically create those routes so I can pull a list of unknown nav items from the db and create those routes in a loop.

So, typically a tutorial will show;

$routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

But what if I don't know what those routes will be in advance?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't create routes dynamically. You can only configure your routes in the module.config(). I think you search for routes with rest parameters.

Here an quick example with a list view and a detail view that shows one item of the list. Assume the backendService to be defined. The resulting url for the list is .../#/list and for the detail view of an item with the id 12345 the url is .../#/list/12345. Note that all route params are interpreted as strings. So routeParams will be `{id: "12345"}`.

In the angular phonecat step [#9](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) is a good example of angular router.

```
angular.module('app').config( function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/list', 
    {
       templateUrl: 'views/list.html', 
       controller:'listCtrl'
    }
  ).when('/list/:id', 
    {
      templateUrl: 'views/detail.html',
      controller: 'detailCtrl'
    })
});
angular.module('app').controller('detailCtrl', 
    function($scope, $routeParams, backendService) {
      $scope.items = backendService.getItemById($routeParams.id);
    }
);
```